# Java: AWS CloudSearch - domain client/config best practice

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a multi-threaded app that makes search calls to AWS CloudSearch (the search endpoint) and document upload calls (to the doc endpoint). I need to use a different `ClientConfiguration` for each, and I see that that class is not thread safe, but I think `AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient` is thread safe. (right?)

Also, regarding `AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient`, the javadoc says, "All service calls made using this client are blocking, and will not return until the service call completes.", so in my multi-threaded web app, does that mean I should create a new domain client for each search request so one user's search doesn't block another? Won't that make each search slow since it takes some time to create the domain client?

I guess the real question is: **what objects can I make static and what needs to be created for every request?**

```
ClientConfiguration searchConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
ClientConfiguration docConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withGzip(true).withRequestTimeout(90000);

AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient searchClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(credentials, searchConfig).withEndpoint(searchEndpoint);
AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient docClient = new AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient(credentials, searchConfig).withEndpoint(searchEndpoint);
```

Update: In my tests, I have it get new `ClientConfiguration` and `AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient` objects for every search and document request. It takes 500-1000ms to get the first one (regardless of whether it's a search or doc request), and then all subsequent requests take <= 10ms. So maybe I should be on the safe side and just create a new object for everything on every request...

Comment: Since the config is not thread safe and the service is blocking, a pool of each client type might be useful.  Each pool factory would know how to create a config instance when creating a related client instance.  The max pool size could be the same as the thread count.  This is assuming a client is re-usable, but only by one thread at a time.